# How to run a java task automatically from an external jar?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I want to generate a java jar which when included on the classpath of another project will launch a periodic task that does something in the background.
This is very similar to eureka client. You include the dependency and add an annotation after which a service is started automatically to poll eureka server.
How can I do that?

Edit: I got it to work using maven, following the example provided in the comments

- github.com/shauank/spring-boot/tree/master/client (client which is having taskexecutor)

  github.com/shauank/spring-boot/tree/master/application (Application which uses jar created in step1)

Comment: are you using springboot?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use concept of *Autoconfiguration*. Same is used by Eureka and Config server.

Under `src/main/resource` create `spring.factories` and add following entry

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
location.to.your.executor
```

Your class,

```
pacakage location.to.your.executor

class MyExecutor{

  public MyExecutor(){
    //Your code for task executor
  }

}
```

Now, above code can be build as jar and included into another spring boot project.

So, when you run another jar, `spring boot` will look for auto configuration onto `spring.factories` class and load classes defined into it.

Comment: thanks, that is what I am looking for; however, I can't seem to make it work; I have a spring boot project using the gradle plugin and I'm building the jar with the 'bootJar' task; I include this on the classpath of another project but it does not seem to pick up my executor

Comment: I do not have more idea about gradle but this solution should work with gradle. If possible, you can share your code base and I would like to see

Comment: Added a PR. Please check and if it does not work then kindly update PR

Comment: That works when running the jar directly. However it is still not picked up if included in another project.

Comment: Added some more code changes. Unfortunately, I do not have gradel env. I tried with maven and it worked expected

Comment: could you give me an example with maven ? (the pom.xml)

Comment: Create two project
1)https://github.com/shauank/spring-boot/tree/master/client (client which is having taskexecutor)
2)https://github.com/shauank/spring-boot/tree/master/application (Application which uses jar created in step1)

Hope this should fix your issue)